# Hyperlink image in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have an image in PowerShell GUI that has an embedded hyperlink to open a web page? For instance, if I had an image of a car in a PowerShell GUI form and when a user clicks the image, it would open https://cars.com.

I've tried all kinds of google searching and never came up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward if you're using Windows Forms - just add an event handler for the `Click` event on the form control that you want to act as a link, then call `Start-Process <URL>` from there:

```
try {
    # ensure dependent assemblies are loaded
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    # create form with a picturebox
    $form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()
    $pictureBox = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox]::new()
    $form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)

    # load image from disk, configure picture box
    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((Convert-Path path\to\image.png))
    $pictureBox.Image = $image
    $pictureBox.Width = $image.Width
    $pictureBox.Height = $image.Height

    # add an event handler for the `Click` event of the picture box
    $pictureBox.add_Click({
        # Start-Process will invoke the default handler for URLs (usually your browser)
        Start-Process 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
    })

    # show form
    $form.ShowDialog()
}
finally {
    # clean up
    $image,$form |ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

---

If you want to make the target control more "link-like", override the *cursor* shown when hovering over to be a hand, just like an anchor in a browser DOM:

```
$pictureBox.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
```